# GDAL open failed-4

Tags: qgis, gdal

In SPHY mdel preprocessor (modules to process) i am facing a problem of GDAL Open Failed-4 (snap is attached).

What could be the reason for this problem and how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: GDALOpen failed - 4 ...
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
this is tha main error